# jquery .val() and .length methods not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code `.val()` returns no result and `.length` always returns '1' for whatever input typed. Where am I going wrong ?

Below is the HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
        <input type="text" name="my_name" id="my_name" >

        <button type="submit"  id="submit_btn1" name="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Javascript file

```
<script> 
        $(function(){
            var value = $("#my_name").val();
            var name_length=$('#my_name').length;
            $('#my_name').keyup(function(){
               alert(name_length);
               alert(value);
           });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: **Working here** http://jsfiddle.net/9NJ6f/ have fun with the demo! `:)`

Comment: "name_length" will always return 1 because you are using the element ID in your selector which is always unique in your page

Comment: @Tats_innit - no worked `:)`... at least for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grabbing the `val` when there is no value. That variable won't automatically update. That's what the `keyup` function is for:

```
$('#my_name').keyup(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

As per the `length`, this is working as intended. Your selector is returning an array of matched elements, and the length of that array is 1.

Edit: Per the comments, if you're actually looking to check the length of your entered value, use `this.value.length`

Comment: I think the op wanted to check the lenght of `this.value`... `this.value.length`

Comment: @Reigel -- Edited the answer to include your snippet, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you assign the Element to the variable it has a value of ''. You have to get the Element when the Event occurs instead, like:

```
$(function(){ // load
var mn = $('my_name');
mn.keyup(function(){
  var value = mn.val(), name_length = mn.length;
  console.log(value); console.log(name_length);
});
}); // end load
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need like this:

HTML:

```
<form id="form">  
  <input type="text" name="my_name" id="my_name" />    
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery: (With `submit` function)

[LIVE DEMO 1](http://jsbin.com/eFOsamIM/1/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#form").on("submit", function(){

    var inputValue  = $("#my_name").val(),
        inputLength = $("#my_name").val().length;

    alert(inputValue);
    alert(inputLength);

  return false; 
  });  
});
```

or with `keyup` function:

[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/eFOsamIM/2/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#my_name").on("keyup", function(){

    var inputValue  = $("#my_name").val(),
        inputLength = $("#my_name").val().length;

    alert(inputValue);
    alert(inputLength);

  });  
});
```